# Symfony Validation - Conditional constraints

Tags: php, symfony

I have a value which can either be a boolean, int or string. Depending on the type additional validation should be done - e.g.: in case the value is `true` the `Type` validation is the only constraint applied, but if the value is `3` I also want to apply the `Range` constraint.

Something like

```
$this->validator->validate($value, [new Type(['int', 'string', 'boolean'], new Range(['min' => 0, 'max' => 2));
```

Doesn't work because every value is checked for proper range which is pointless if the value is something like `"true"` or `false`.

Comment: You should first check the type of the value and then: set a proper validation group or add contstraints manually depends on that check.

Comment: or create a custom validation for your use case

Comment: Just in case you are missing some key concept in symfony form data transformer, why would you need 3 type in a form type? (it may help us to guide you on a simple solution)

Comment: There's no form, I use the validator on raw values.